# Regarding Symmetric transitive closures

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $Q'$ be the transitive closure of some relation $R'$, and let $S'$ be the symmetric closure of $Q'$. Must it be the case that $S'$ is transitive as well.

Comment: Is the following counterexample good enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please point out any mistakes

**Sol.** No. Consider the following counterexample.

Let $A = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$.

Let $R = \{(a,b),(a,e),(e,d),(c,d),(c,b)\}$

then $Q' = R\cup\{(a,d)\}$

then $S' = R\cup\{(a,d)\}\cup\{(d,a),(b,a),(e,a),(d,e),(d,c),(b,c)\}$

$S'$ is not transitive because $(b,c)\in S'$ and $(c,e)\in S'$ but $(b,e)\not\in S'$.

Comment: Yep, that works.

Comment: Note that you already get a counterexample if you restrict your order to $\{b,c,d\}$.

Comment: Im sorry i dont follow

Comment: oh ok nevermind yes your quite right